# When are go goose transactions committed?

Tags: go, sqltransaction

- I have some code that needs to be run in a `Tx` like [here](https://go.dev/doc/database/execute-transactions)
- I generated a go sql migration as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/master/examples/go-migrations/00002_rename_root.go) in the official docs for `go goose`

my questions are:

- when are these transactions actually `committed` to the database?
- I forced the migrations to be committed with `tx.Commit()`. Here's my migration file in go:

```golang
func Up00002(tx *sql.Tx) error {
    _, err := tx.Exec("UPDATE users SET username='admin' WHERE username='root';")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error during committing the transaction: %w", err)
    }


    return nil
}
```

I am unable to run the above migration after the `down` part as I get the `ErrTxDone` ([source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=2185)) when I run them. I  still want to run the go migration `Up00002` multiple times (for testing). How can I do this? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just going through their documentations [here](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/c462979327385eb7bf68e5bf2e232e8fbd3f9773/migration.go#L183) shows that the commit already happens in an `AddMigrations` call - this is with transactions ofc and is handled internally by `go goose` - pretty nice :)

The same is true for sql as well, as we see it [here](https://github.com/pressly/goose/blob/c462979327385eb7bf68e5bf2e232e8fbd3f9773/migration_sql.go#L63)

The pkg also provides `--no-transaction` option which we can use to have full control of the `db` object - awesome!